# Orchard CMS: Page not found for the custom module

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules

I am creating the custom module, but when I tried to navigate to it, I get 404 error.

Custom Module:

[image]

404 Error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Things to check:

- is your module enabled?
- what is the name of your module in the module.txt file as this will be in the route instead of the module project name
- it also looks like you are using a custom module location (orchard only picks up modules in the Modules folder by default), so make sure you've added your custom module to the web.config. see here for details http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Orchard-module-loader-and-dynamic-compilation/#custom-folders